# Swingtools extension of JXTable and JTable, hiding columns return index out of bounds

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm evaluating Swingtools JTable, an open source and more powerful version of JTable and JXTable. As the maintainer Ivan Portyankin explains it on his blog [ipsoftware blog](http://www.ipsoftware.ru/blog/):

> "Sometimes it may seem that standard Swing JTable or its close
>   companions like SwingX JXTable are too limited. You don’t have too
>   many funny ways to manipulate them – they are strict rectangular
>   grids, with every row taking fixed amount of screen space in pixels
>   and columns taken from one and only column model. Columns cannot be
>   spanned or split and always take a single cell in the grid."

Now I am investigating the ability of hiding columns, this can be done via its interface: [image: swingtools table] However I'd like to hide by default some columns and store the preference when the user manually re-enables them so to show always the last chosen preference.

Below I try to hide all columns as default but I incur in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error!!

```
public class AdvancedTableDemo extends JFrame
{
    public AdvancedTableDemo()
    {
        super("Advanced Table Demo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 300);

        final BaseTable baseTable = new BaseTable();
        baseTable.setFilterHeaderEnabled(true);
        add(new JScrollPane(baseTable));
        BeanPropertyTableModel<TableBean> model = new BeanPropertyTableModel<TableBean>(TableBean.class);
        model.setOrderedProperties(Arrays.asList("name", "surname", "date"));
        model.setData(TableBean.generateList(100));
        baseTable.setModel(model);

        int j = baseTable.getColumnCount(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
        {
            TableColumnExt tableColumnExt = baseTable.getColumnExt(i);
            tableColumnExt.setVisible(false);
        }
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new AdvancedTableDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 1
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:294)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTable.getColumn(JXTable.java:2265)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTable.getColumnExt(JXTable.java:2415)
    at demo.table.AdvancedTableDemo.<init>(AdvancedTableDemo.java:46)
    at demo.table.AdvancedTableDemo$1.run(AdvancedTableDemo.java:62)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

The column count is 3, but getting anything greater than column 1 yields the error just seen! tried with 17 columns and anything greater than 10 returns exception.

Am I missing something here??

Comment: Try this: instead of `baseTable.setModel(model);`, do `final BaseTable baseTable = new BaseTable(model);`. Rearrange lines as needed. Still have that problem then?

Comment: There's no constructor with a model as parameter, only a constructor of BaseTable with no parameter. See source code: https://github.com/thirdy/swingtools/blob/master/src/main/java/com/porty/swing/table/BaseTable.java

Comment: The reason I suggested that, is that for [`JTable.setModel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setModel(javax.swing.table.TableModel)) documentation it states: *"Sets the data model for this table to newModel and registers with it for listener notifications from the new data model."*. Nothing about setting up the column model for you (as in the constructor of [`JTable( TableModel )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable(javax.swing.table.TableModel))).

Comment: the point where I hide the column is not dealing with the model actually but with a TableColumnExt, how that relates to the model I have yet to figure out. But I see no way of doing what you said for now.

Comment: I suggest you alter the `BaseTable` class, add a constructor that takes a `TableModel` to call `super(dm);`  (and does the other stuff in the parameter-less constructor), and use that constructor. By contract, the `JXTable` and `JTable` constructor for `TableModel` should create the `ColumnModel` for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The column count is 3, but getting anything greater than column 1 yields the error

```
int j = baseTable.getColumnCount(true);
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
```

Yes, but after you hide the first column there are only 2. Then after you hide the next column there is only one (so you get the exception).

So the solution is to hide the columns from the end of the table, not the beginning:

```
int j = baseTable.getColumnCount(true) -1;
for (int i = j; i >= 0;  i--)
```

Comment: Thank you, I feel so dumb but really could not figure this out! I'll need some sleep...